# finding associations in dataset with list of string data in each cell in R

Tags: r, associations, text-mining

I am looking for finding a method to find the association between words in the table (or list). In each cell of the table, I have several words separated by ";".

lets say I have a table as below; some words are 'af' or 'aa' belong to one cell.

```
df<-read.table(text="
A           B            C           D
af;aa;az    bf;bb        c;cc       df;dd
aa;az       bf;bc        c          dc;dd
ah;al;aa    bb           c;cd       dd
af;aa       bf           cc         dd",header=T,stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I want to find associations between all words in the entire dataset, between cells(not interested in within cell association). for example, how many times `aa` and `dd` appear in one row, or show me which words have the highest association (e.g. aa with bb, aa with dd,....).

expected output: (the numbers can be inaccurate and association rep does not have be shown with '--')

```
2 pairs association (numbers can be counts, probability or normalized association)
association    number of associations 
aa--dd          3
aa--c           3
bb--dd          2
...
3 pairs association
aa--bb--dd      3
aa--bb--c       3
...

4 pairs association
aa--bb--c--dd   2
aa--bf--c--dd   2
...
```

can you help me to implement it in R?
Tx

Comment: @akrun I updated the question and expected output. Tx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if you have something like the approach below in mind. It is basically a custom function which we use in a nested `purrr::map` call. The outer call loops over the number of pairs: `2`,`3`, `4` and the inner call uses `combn` to create all possible combinations as input and uses the custom function to create the desired output.

```r
library(tidyverse)

count_pairs <- function(x) {
s <- seq(x)
 df[, x] %>% 
    reduce(s, separate_rows, .init = ., sep = ";")  
    group_by(across()) %>% 
    count() %>% 
    rename(set_names(s))
}

map(2:4,
    ~ map_dfr(combn(1:4, .x, simplify = FALSE),
                    count_pairs) %>% arrange(-n))
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 50 x 3
#> # Groups:   1, 2 [50]
#>    `1`   `2`       n
#>    <chr> <chr> <int>
#>  1 aa    dd        4
#>  2 aa    bf        3
#>  3 aa    c         3
#>  4 bf    dd        3
#>  5 c     dd        3
#>  6 aa    bb        2
#>  7 af    bf        2
#>  8 az    bf        2
#>  9 aa    cc        2
#> 10 af    cc        2
#> # ... with 40 more rows
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 70 x 4
#> # Groups:   1, 2, 3 [70]
#>    `1`   `2`   `3`       n
#>    <chr> <chr> <chr> <int>
#>  1 aa    bf    dd        3
#>  2 aa    c     dd        3
#>  3 aa    bb    c         2
#>  4 aa    bf    c         2
#>  5 aa    bf    cc        2
#>  6 af    bf    cc        2
#>  7 az    bf    c         2
#>  8 aa    bb    dd        2
#>  9 af    bf    dd        2
#> 10 az    bf    dd        2
#> # ... with 60 more rows
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> # A tibble: 35 x 5
#> # Groups:   1, 2, 3, 4 [35]
#>    `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`       n
#>    <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <int>
#>  1 aa    bb    c     dd        2
#>  2 aa    bf    c     dd        2
#>  3 aa    bf    cc    dd        2
#>  4 af    bf    cc    dd        2
#>  5 az    bf    c     dd        2
#>  6 aa    bb    c     df        1
#>  7 aa    bb    cc    dd        1
#>  8 aa    bb    cc    df        1
#>  9 aa    bb    cd    dd        1
#> 10 aa    bc    c     dc        1
#> # ... with 25 more rows

# the data
df<-read.table(text="
A           B            C           D
af;aa;az    bf;bb        c;cc       df;dd
aa;az       bf;bc        c          dc;dd
ah;al;aa    bb           c;cd       dd
af;aa       bf           cc         dd",header=T,stringsAsFactors = F)
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: sorry, there is a small problem. It separates based on any non-alphabetic character. Separation only should happen with ";" . could you fix it ? Tx

Comment: @Cina: I now specified the `sep` argument of `separate_rows`. This should solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the base R code below

```
lst <- apply(df, 1, function(x) sort(unlist(strsplit(x, ";"))))
res <- lapply(
  2:4,
  function(k) {
    setNames(
      data.frame(
        table(
          unlist(
            sapply(
              lst,
              function(v) combn(v, k, paste0, collapse = "--")
            )
          )
        )
      ), c("association", "count")
    )
  }
)
```

and you will see that

```
> res
[[1]]
   association count
1       aa--af     2
2       aa--ah     1
3       aa--al     1
4       aa--az     2
5       aa--bb     2
6       aa--bc     1
7       aa--bf     3
8        aa--c     3
9       aa--cc     2
10      aa--cd     1
11      aa--dc     1
12      aa--dd     4
13      aa--df     1
14      af--az     1
15      af--bb     1
16      af--bf     2
17       af--c     1
18      af--cc     2
19      af--dd     2
20      af--df     1
21      ah--al     1
22      ah--bb     1
23       ah--c     1
24      ah--cd     1
25      ah--dd     1
26      al--bb     1
27       al--c     1
28      al--cd     1
29      al--dd     1
30      az--bb     1
31      az--bc     1
32      az--bf     2
33       az--c     2
34      az--cc     1
35      az--dc     1
36      az--dd     2
37      az--df     1
38      bb--bf     1
39       bb--c     2
40      bb--cc     1
41      bb--cd     1
42      bb--dd     2
43      bb--df     1
44      bc--bf     1
45       bc--c     1
46      bc--dc     1
47      bc--dd     1
48       bf--c     2
49      bf--cc     2
50      bf--dc     1
51      bf--dd     3
52      bf--df     1
53       c--cc     1
54       c--cd     1
55       c--dc     1
56       c--dd     3
57       c--df     1
58      cc--dd     2
59      cc--df     1
60      cd--dd     1
61      dc--dd     1
62      dd--df     1

[[2]]
    association count
1    aa--af--az     1
2    aa--af--bb     1
3    aa--af--bf     2
4     aa--af--c     1
5    aa--af--cc     2
6    aa--af--dd     2
7    aa--af--df     1
8    aa--ah--al     1
9    aa--ah--bb     1
10    aa--ah--c     1
11   aa--ah--cd     1
12   aa--ah--dd     1
13   aa--al--bb     1
14    aa--al--c     1
15   aa--al--cd     1
16   aa--al--dd     1
17   aa--az--bb     1
18   aa--az--bc     1
19   aa--az--bf     2
20    aa--az--c     2
21   aa--az--cc     1
22   aa--az--dc     1
23   aa--az--dd     2
24   aa--az--df     1
25   aa--bb--bf     1
26    aa--bb--c     2
27   aa--bb--cc     1
28   aa--bb--cd     1
29   aa--bb--dd     2
30   aa--bb--df     1
31   aa--bc--bf     1
32    aa--bc--c     1
33   aa--bc--dc     1
34   aa--bc--dd     1
35    aa--bf--c     2
36   aa--bf--cc     2
37   aa--bf--dc     1
38   aa--bf--dd     3
39   aa--bf--df     1
40    aa--c--cc     1
41    aa--c--cd     1
42    aa--c--dc     1
43    aa--c--dd     3
44    aa--c--df     1
45   aa--cc--dd     2
46   aa--cc--df     1
47   aa--cd--dd     1
48   aa--dc--dd     1
49   aa--dd--df     1
50   af--az--bb     1
51   af--az--bf     1
52    af--az--c     1
53   af--az--cc     1
54   af--az--dd     1
55   af--az--df     1
56   af--bb--bf     1
57    af--bb--c     1
58   af--bb--cc     1
59   af--bb--dd     1
60   af--bb--df     1
61    af--bf--c     1
62   af--bf--cc     2
63   af--bf--dd     2
64   af--bf--df     1
65    af--c--cc     1
66    af--c--dd     1
67    af--c--df     1
68   af--cc--dd     2
69   af--cc--df     1
70   af--dd--df     1
71   ah--al--bb     1
72    ah--al--c     1
73   ah--al--cd     1
74   ah--al--dd     1
75    ah--bb--c     1
76   ah--bb--cd     1
77   ah--bb--dd     1
78    ah--c--cd     1
79    ah--c--dd     1
80   ah--cd--dd     1
81    al--bb--c     1
82   al--bb--cd     1
83   al--bb--dd     1
84    al--c--cd     1
85    al--c--dd     1
86   al--cd--dd     1
87   az--bb--bf     1
88    az--bb--c     1
89   az--bb--cc     1
90   az--bb--dd     1
91   az--bb--df     1
92   az--bc--bf     1
93    az--bc--c     1
94   az--bc--dc     1
95   az--bc--dd     1
96    az--bf--c     2
97   az--bf--cc     1
98   az--bf--dc     1
99   az--bf--dd     2
100  az--bf--df     1
101   az--c--cc     1
102   az--c--dc     1
103   az--c--dd     2
104   az--c--df     1
105  az--cc--dd     1
106  az--cc--df     1
107  az--dc--dd     1
108  az--dd--df     1
109   bb--bf--c     1
110  bb--bf--cc     1
111  bb--bf--dd     1
112  bb--bf--df     1
113   bb--c--cc     1
114   bb--c--cd     1
115   bb--c--dd     2
116   bb--c--df     1
117  bb--cc--dd     1
118  bb--cc--df     1
119  bb--cd--dd     1
120  bb--dd--df     1
121   bc--bf--c     1
122  bc--bf--dc     1
123  bc--bf--dd     1
124   bc--c--dc     1
125   bc--c--dd     1
126  bc--dc--dd     1
127   bf--c--cc     1
128   bf--c--dc     1
129   bf--c--dd     2
130   bf--c--df     1
131  bf--cc--dd     2
132  bf--cc--df     1
133  bf--dc--dd     1
134  bf--dd--df     1
135   c--cc--dd     1
136   c--cc--df     1
137   c--cd--dd     1
138   c--dc--dd     1
139   c--dd--df     1
140  cc--dd--df     1

[[3]]
       association count
1   aa--af--az--bb     1
2   aa--af--az--bf     1
3    aa--af--az--c     1
4   aa--af--az--cc     1
5   aa--af--az--dd     1
6   aa--af--az--df     1
7   aa--af--bb--bf     1
8    aa--af--bb--c     1
9   aa--af--bb--cc     1
10  aa--af--bb--dd     1
11  aa--af--bb--df     1
12   aa--af--bf--c     1
13  aa--af--bf--cc     2
14  aa--af--bf--dd     2
15  aa--af--bf--df     1
16   aa--af--c--cc     1
17   aa--af--c--dd     1
18   aa--af--c--df     1
19  aa--af--cc--dd     2
20  aa--af--cc--df     1
21  aa--af--dd--df     1
22  aa--ah--al--bb     1
23   aa--ah--al--c     1
24  aa--ah--al--cd     1
25  aa--ah--al--dd     1
26   aa--ah--bb--c     1
27  aa--ah--bb--cd     1
28  aa--ah--bb--dd     1
29   aa--ah--c--cd     1
30   aa--ah--c--dd     1
31  aa--ah--cd--dd     1
32   aa--al--bb--c     1
33  aa--al--bb--cd     1
34  aa--al--bb--dd     1
35   aa--al--c--cd     1
36   aa--al--c--dd     1
37  aa--al--cd--dd     1
38  aa--az--bb--bf     1
39   aa--az--bb--c     1
40  aa--az--bb--cc     1
41  aa--az--bb--dd     1
42  aa--az--bb--df     1
43  aa--az--bc--bf     1
44   aa--az--bc--c     1
45  aa--az--bc--dc     1
46  aa--az--bc--dd     1
47   aa--az--bf--c     2
48  aa--az--bf--cc     1
49  aa--az--bf--dc     1
50  aa--az--bf--dd     2
51  aa--az--bf--df     1
52   aa--az--c--cc     1
53   aa--az--c--dc     1
54   aa--az--c--dd     2
55   aa--az--c--df     1
56  aa--az--cc--dd     1
57  aa--az--cc--df     1
58  aa--az--dc--dd     1
59  aa--az--dd--df     1
60   aa--bb--bf--c     1
61  aa--bb--bf--cc     1
62  aa--bb--bf--dd     1
63  aa--bb--bf--df     1
64   aa--bb--c--cc     1
65   aa--bb--c--cd     1
66   aa--bb--c--dd     2
67   aa--bb--c--df     1
68  aa--bb--cc--dd     1
69  aa--bb--cc--df     1
70  aa--bb--cd--dd     1
71  aa--bb--dd--df     1
72   aa--bc--bf--c     1
73  aa--bc--bf--dc     1
74  aa--bc--bf--dd     1
75   aa--bc--c--dc     1
76   aa--bc--c--dd     1
77  aa--bc--dc--dd     1
78   aa--bf--c--cc     1
79   aa--bf--c--dc     1
80   aa--bf--c--dd     2
81   aa--bf--c--df     1
82  aa--bf--cc--dd     2
83  aa--bf--cc--df     1
84  aa--bf--dc--dd     1
85  aa--bf--dd--df     1
86   aa--c--cc--dd     1
87   aa--c--cc--df     1
88   aa--c--cd--dd     1
89   aa--c--dc--dd     1
90   aa--c--dd--df     1
91  aa--cc--dd--df     1
92  af--az--bb--bf     1
93   af--az--bb--c     1
94  af--az--bb--cc     1
95  af--az--bb--dd     1
96  af--az--bb--df     1
97   af--az--bf--c     1
98  af--az--bf--cc     1
99  af--az--bf--dd     1
100 af--az--bf--df     1
101  af--az--c--cc     1
102  af--az--c--dd     1
103  af--az--c--df     1
104 af--az--cc--dd     1
105 af--az--cc--df     1
106 af--az--dd--df     1
107  af--bb--bf--c     1
108 af--bb--bf--cc     1
109 af--bb--bf--dd     1
110 af--bb--bf--df     1
111  af--bb--c--cc     1
112  af--bb--c--dd     1
113  af--bb--c--df     1
114 af--bb--cc--dd     1
115 af--bb--cc--df     1
116 af--bb--dd--df     1
117  af--bf--c--cc     1
118  af--bf--c--dd     1
119  af--bf--c--df     1
120 af--bf--cc--dd     2
121 af--bf--cc--df     1
122 af--bf--dd--df     1
123  af--c--cc--dd     1
124  af--c--cc--df     1
125  af--c--dd--df     1
126 af--cc--dd--df     1
127  ah--al--bb--c     1
128 ah--al--bb--cd     1
129 ah--al--bb--dd     1
130  ah--al--c--cd     1
131  ah--al--c--dd     1
132 ah--al--cd--dd     1
133  ah--bb--c--cd     1
134  ah--bb--c--dd     1
135 ah--bb--cd--dd     1
136  ah--c--cd--dd     1
137  al--bb--c--cd     1
138  al--bb--c--dd     1
139 al--bb--cd--dd     1
140  al--c--cd--dd     1
141  az--bb--bf--c     1
142 az--bb--bf--cc     1
143 az--bb--bf--dd     1
144 az--bb--bf--df     1
145  az--bb--c--cc     1
146  az--bb--c--dd     1
147  az--bb--c--df     1
148 az--bb--cc--dd     1
149 az--bb--cc--df     1
150 az--bb--dd--df     1
151  az--bc--bf--c     1
152 az--bc--bf--dc     1
153 az--bc--bf--dd     1
154  az--bc--c--dc     1
155  az--bc--c--dd     1
156 az--bc--dc--dd     1
157  az--bf--c--cc     1
158  az--bf--c--dc     1
159  az--bf--c--dd     2
160  az--bf--c--df     1
161 az--bf--cc--dd     1
162 az--bf--cc--df     1
163 az--bf--dc--dd     1
164 az--bf--dd--df     1
165  az--c--cc--dd     1
166  az--c--cc--df     1
167  az--c--dc--dd     1
168  az--c--dd--df     1
169 az--cc--dd--df     1
170  bb--bf--c--cc     1
171  bb--bf--c--dd     1
172  bb--bf--c--df     1
173 bb--bf--cc--dd     1
174 bb--bf--cc--df     1
175 bb--bf--dd--df     1
176  bb--c--cc--dd     1
177  bb--c--cc--df     1
178  bb--c--cd--dd     1
179  bb--c--dd--df     1
180 bb--cc--dd--df     1
181  bc--bf--c--dc     1
182  bc--bf--c--dd     1
183 bc--bf--dc--dd     1
184  bc--c--dc--dd     1
185  bf--c--cc--dd     1
186  bf--c--cc--df     1
187  bf--c--dc--dd     1
188  bf--c--dd--df     1
189 bf--cc--dd--df     1
190  c--cc--dd--df     1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df<-read.table(text="
A           B            C           D
af;aa;az    bf;bb        c;cc       df;dd
aa;az       bf;bc        c          dc;dd
ah;al;aa    bb           c;cd       dd
af;aa       bf           cc         dd",header=T,stringsAsFactors = F)

df<-apply(df, 2, function(x) gsub(";", " ", x))
df2<-as.data.frame(apply(df, 2,function(x) paste(x[1:4],sep = "," )))
df3<-splitstackshape::cSplit(df2, c("A", "B", "C","D"), " ")
df4<-as.data.frame(t(df3))

A<-expand.grid(df4[,1],df4[,1])
B<-expand.grid(df4[,2],df4[,2])
C<-expand.grid(df4[,3],df4[,3])
D<-expand.grid(df4[,4],df4[,4])

DF_list<-bind_rows(A,B,C,D)
DF_list$Var1 == DF_list$Var2 -> DF_list$filter
DF_list[DF_list$filter == "FALSE", ]-> DF_list
DF_list$Var1<-as.character(DF_list$Var1)
DF_list$Var2<-as.character(DF_list$Var2)
DF_list[nchar(DF_list$Var1) > 0, ]-> DF_list
DF_list[nchar(DF_list$Var2) > 0, ]-> DF_list
pair_df<-data.frame("pairs" = paste(DF_list[["Var1"]], "--", DF_list[["Var2"]], sep = ""))
pairs<-data.frame("combos"= table(pair_df$pairs))


####output###
    combos.Var1 combos.Freq
1        aa--af           2
2        aa--ah           1
3        aa--al           1
4        aa--az           2
5        aa--bb           2
6        aa--bc           1
7        aa--bf           3
8         aa--c           3
9        aa--cc           2
10       aa--cd           1
11       aa--dc           1
12       aa--dd           4
13       aa--df           1
14       af--aa           2
15       af--az           1
16       af--bb           1
17       af--bf           2
18        af--c           1
19       af--cc           2
20       af--dd           2
21       af--df           1
22       ah--aa           1
23       ah--al           1
24       ah--bb           1
25        ah--c           1
26       ah--cd           1
27       ah--dd           1
28       al--aa           1
29       al--ah           1
30       al--bb           1
31        al--c           1
32       al--cd           1
33       al--dd           1
34       az--aa           2
35       az--af           1
36       az--bb           1
37       az--bc           1
38       az--bf           2
39        az--c           2
40       az--cc           1
41       az--dc           1
42       az--dd           2
43       az--df           1
44       bb--aa           2
45       bb--af           1
46       bb--ah           1
47       bb--al           1
48       bb--az           1
49       bb--bf           1
50        bb--c           2
51       bb--cc           1
52       bb--cd           1
53       bb--dd           2
54       bb--df           1
55       bc--aa           1
56       bc--az           1
57       bc--bf           1
58        bc--c           1
59       bc--dc           1
60       bc--dd           1
61       bf--aa           3
62       bf--af           2
63       bf--az           2
64       bf--bb           1
65       bf--bc           1
66        bf--c           2
67       bf--cc           2
68       bf--dc           1
69       bf--dd           3
70       bf--df           1
71        c--aa           3
72        c--af           1
73        c--ah           1
74        c--al           1
75        c--az           2
76        c--bb           2
77        c--bc           1
78        c--bf           2
79        c--cc           1
80        c--cd           1
81        c--dc           1
82        c--dd           3
83        c--df           1
84       cc--aa           2
85       cc--af           2
86       cc--az           1
87       cc--bb           1
88       cc--bf           2
89        cc--c           1
90       cc--dd           2
91       cc--df           1
92       cd--aa           1
93       cd--ah           1
94       cd--al           1
95       cd--bb           1
96        cd--c           1
97       cd--dd           1
98       dc--aa           1
99       dc--az           1
100      dc--bc           1
101      dc--bf           1
102       dc--c           1
103      dc--dd           1
104      dd--aa           4
105      dd--af           2
106      dd--ah           1
107      dd--al           1
108      dd--az           2
109      dd--bb           2
110      dd--bc           1
111      dd--bf           3
112       dd--c           3
113      dd--cc           2
114      dd--cd           1
115      dd--dc           1
116      dd--df           1
117      df--aa           1
118      df--af           1
119      df--az           1
120      df--bb           1
121      df--bf           1
122       df--c           1
123      df--cc           1
124      df--dd           1
```